# sugarcrm can't login returning Token Expired

Tags: php, sugarcrm

When I try to login Suger Crm via login screen.every time appear .

```
Token Expired Your token is invalid or has expired. Please login again
```

for fixed this I done several things according to documentations.

I try to changing life time in my **config_override.php**

```
$sugar_config['oauth2']['access_token_lifetime']    = 3600;
 $sugar_config['oauth2']['refresh_token_lifetime']    =  3600;
 $sugar_config['oauth2']['max_session_lifetime']    =  3600;
```

but same results it appearing same error message .
also I checked is there any error on  **sugarcrm.log**
but not found anything.

Comment: This might be an issue with the server rather than Sugar.  Check the various session settings in php.ini and ensure there's free disk space on the server to create the sessions.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The configured directory for "session.save_path" needs to be writeable by the user that is running PHP-FPM or Apache (if using mod_php).